# ASP.Net Visual Studio 2017 MVC routing view not opening on Azure/server yet does on IISExpress

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to ASP.Net MVC. I've searched and reviewed many answers but still can't find a solution.

I have an ASP.Net MVC application which behaves differently locally to when deployed.  I get 404 not found when attempting to open the 'Companies\Index' view when deployed top Azure, and to other hosting provider, but it works when run locally in Visual Studio/IIS Express.

I am using the default routing provided by the initial 'new app wizard'.  Is there anything I am missing which may mean I get 404 when hitting http:\myappname\Companies\Index or http:\myname\Companies?

**Action I am trying click on to open new 'Companies' view...**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Manage";
}

<h2>Manage</h2>
<p>Choose an item below to configure settings</p>
<div class="">
    <ul>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Companies", "Index", "Companies") </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Directory structure of application in Visual Studio...**

[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDmwi.png)

**Routing...**

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
        // Set default erorr handler page
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error.html");

        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddJsonFile(env.ContentRootPath+ "/config.json")
            .Build();

        // Set Developer Exceptions on if in development mode
        if (configuration.GetValue<bool>("FeatureToggles:EnableDeveloperExceptions"))
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            });
       }
    }
}
```

**Controller Index action I am trying to invoke to return the Companies\Index view...**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Daylight.Data;
using Daylight.Models;

namespace Daylight.Controllers
{
public class CompaniesController : Controller
{
    private readonly DaylightDataContext _context;

    public CompaniesController(DaylightDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Companies
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await _context.Companies.ToListAsync());
    }
```

I'd be very grateful for any pointers!!

Comment: You should copy/paste the code and use the four space indentation to make this more readable.

Comment: You have posted the code for the Projects controller, though you have asked about the Companies route (perhaps this is simply a typo) but without looking at the correct code there's little we can do.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I will do as you have suggested, thanks

Comment: Is this the exact code you're running? It looks correct to me. Meaning if you were getting an error in `await _context.Companies.ToListAsync()` I'd expect a non 404 response; however, if this is simplified there could be something in your real code causing the 404 that we're not seeing.

Comment: Thank you very much for looking at this.  This is the exact code.  There is obviously other files in the project i've only posted what i believe relevant.  It does work when running in Visual Studio.  When publishing to Azure, or to another ISP the Companies tab returns a 404 hence why I thought routing.

Comment: Do other routes work when published?

Comment: I will try this and update the post, thanks

Comment: Can you share the web.config that is on the published server?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was down to the website not being able to access the database, and therefore not able to return data to the view hence why the view appeared blank.